# Jquery and php(ajax) 2021 is not equal to 2021

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I have a problem I can't understand. I did many test but the result just disturb me. I have an ajax request from where I get my data like that :

```
$check = 0;
$output = '';

while($data = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result1)){
    if($check == 0){
        $output = $data['license'];
        $check = 1;
    }else{
        $output .= ','.$data['license'];
    }
}
echo $output;
```

the output is "2020,2021" at the end. now I have my alert in js to test the result :

```
success: function(data) {
          alert(data); //get "2020,2021" from this alert
          var tab = data.split(',');
          alert(tab[0]+','+tab[1]); //get "2020,2021" from this alert
          if(tab[0]=='2020'){
            alert('yes1');
          }else{
            alert('no1');
          }
          if(tab[1]=='2021'){
            alert('yes2');
          }else{
            alert('no2');
          }
}
```

But now the problem is : the two other alerts I have are "yes1" and "no2" .... how can my 2020 equal to 2020 and 2021 not equal to 2021.
I just can't understand, if someone can help.

Update : when I alert tab[1]+','+tab[0] I have :

"2021

,2020"

I don't get when it is possible to append (my "SELECT * FROM `my_table` WHERE license='2021' " get all the results, so it's not in my database)

Comment: console.log(data) to see you DO get `2020,2021` and not `2020, 2021` - add a trim()

Comment: Maybe you have some non-printable chars?

Comment: Is `tab[1].length` === 4? If it's 5, there might be a newline following it (`"2021\n"` rather than `"2021"`)

Comment: I suggest you create an array and echo a json version of it, then you do not need to test if you need a comma

Comment: ok my "tab[1].length" result 12 .... so it's the problem, but how can I find where the problem come from ? I just didn't add all that characters and my sql query would result nothing with ="2021" if it was the problem, right ?

Comment: The trim() just work but now if it's possible I would like to understand

Comment: Simple data have a space and trim remove that, now compare work because data is equal. (without space)

Comment: Just the little recommendation: To avoid this kind of formatting errors, it is better to use something like JSON (you can represent arrays in JSON also). Use `json_encode` for PHP output, `$.getJSON` or `dataType` setting in `$.ajax` to receive it. Do not use alerts but `console.log()` to see and manipulate exact output.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (change `success =` to `success :` in your code

```js
success = function(data) {
  console.log(data); //get "2020,2021" from this alert
  const [tab0, tab1] = data.split(',');
  console.log(tab0 === '2020' ? 'yes0' : 'no0');
  console.log(tab1 === '2021' ? 'yes1' : 'no1');
}

  
// testing 
success("2020,2021")
success("2020, 2021")
```

Then try this:

```js
success = function(data) {
  console.log(data); //get "2020,2021" from this alert
  const [tab0, tab1] = data.match(/\d{4}/g);
  console.log(tab0 === '2020' ? 'yes0' : 'no0');
  console.log(tab1 === '2021' ? 'yes1' : 'no1');
}

// testing 
success("2020,2021")
success("2020, 2021")
```

Answer (score -2):

As you can see if data is correct script work:

```js
          var data='2020,2021';
          var tab = data.split(',');
          alert(tab[0]+','+tab[1]); //get "2020,2021" from this alert
          if(tab[0]=='2020'){
            alert('yes1');
          }else{
            alert('no1');
          }
          if(tab[1]=='2021'){
            alert('yes2');
          }else{
            alert('no2');
          }
```

Comment: How do you know that data is correct and same as in OP question?

Comment: The question is _how is it possible that the script doesn't work?_ I reply: "it works but the data is wrong"

Comment: I simply made sure that the system works, not "_on my machine_" but on all of them.